# Having trouble getting IIS bindings with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis

I am doing this.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\Sites
```

Which works, but I want to select specific items and then export into a file. I want to select Name, State, and Bindings. So something like this;

```
Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\Sites | select-object name, state, bindings
```

The problem is, bindings appears to be an array. How can I loop through that and get the bindings? Should I use like a PSCustomObject? How could I loop through the bindings array and get the actual bindings?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the `Bindings` property contain multiple objects, or just multiple strings? If it's the former, you should be able to do: `Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\Sites | select-object Name, State -Expand Bindings`

Comment: Sorry, I had tried that but it doesn't allow you to export the bindings. I tried format-table but it cuts off state and name. I tried to export as it was and it doesn't export the bindings. Thank you. Expand does display the bindings, just doesn't let me export the binding values.

Comment: After the death of IIS 7.x, all supported IIS versions today support the new IISAdministration PowerShell cmdlets, so you should use `Get-IISSiteBinding` instead, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/get-iissitebinding?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: I probably should, but if I don't know how - that makes it a little hard.

Comment: PSCustomObject has an easy way to create structured data. You might try using hashtables. A hash table is more like an object, a collection of key/value pairs that can be accessed and used like a normal object.

Answer (score 0):

Method I've ended up using is :

```
$allData=@()
Foreach ($Site in get-website) {
    Foreach ($Bind in $Site.bindings.collection) {
        $data = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name=$Site.name;
            State=$Site.state;
            Protocol=$Bind.Protocol;
            IPAddress=$(if ($bind -like '*`[*') { ((($Bind -split "]")[0]).Split('[')[-1]) } else {$Bind.BindingInformation.Split(":")[0]})
            Port=$Bind.BindingInformation.Split(":")[-2]
            HostHeader=$Bind.BindingInformation.Split(":")[-1]
        }
        $allData+=$data
    }
}
```

which creates a PSCustomObject for each, and then adds the result to an array `$allData` from where it can be queried.

It seems the binding information is essentially presented as a string, for instance :

```
123.123.123.123:80:mydomain.com
123.123.123.123:80:www.mydomain.com
123.123.123.123:443:mydomain.com
123.123.123.123:443:www.mydomain.com
```

so you need to use `-Split` to separate out the IP Address, Port Number, and Host Address, but since they're delimited using a `:` that breaks if it's using a IPv6 address. That's why the `IPAddress=` section is so complicated, as that copes with both IPv4 and IPv6.

Once the above is run you can query the array in various ways as needed, for instance, `$allData` to return everything, `$allData[5]` to retrieve the 6th set of binding information in the array, `$allData[5].Port` to retrieve just the Port number from the 6th set of binding information, query the array with `$allData | Where {$_.Protocol -eq "https"}` to retrieve all entries your where clause, or just select the specific subset of information you need at that time, using `$allData | Select Name,State,Port`